# how to parse this date 2016-03-29T00:00:00+01:00 with GsonBuilder on Android

Tags: android, gson

Hi in a JSON response i have the two dates, `"2016-03-29T00:00:00+01:00"` and `"2016-03-27T00:00:00Z"` in this structure something like `[{date:2016-03-29T00:00:00+01:00},{date:2016-03-27T00:00:00Z}]` how to parse this using `Gson` or `GsonBuilder`. Please keep in mind using android.

Thanks

Comment: these are iso8601 compliant time stamps there is 660kb library for parsing strings like these called joda time gson is a json parser not a timestamp parser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: If this is your json structure then your json is not a valid json..

Answer (score 0):

these are iso8601 compliant time stamps there is 660kb library for parsing strings like these called joda time gson is a json parser not a timestamp parser, you can take a look at this answer for [converting iso8601 time stamps to java.util.date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) , both the question and the answer explain in detail how to do this.

If the format of the date string isn't going to change then for now you could try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat ISO8601DATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
Date date = ISO8601DATEFORMAT.parse(date);
```

I personally had been using the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` for quite a while to parse iso8601 timestamps, but have now moved to using joda time.

Answer (score 0):

There is [setDateFormat()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat(java.lang.String)) method in `GsonBuilder` where you can specify date format you need